# How to do vector calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How do you do vector calculus. For some reason I have not found a single resource that explains step by step how to correctly do vector calculus. No, matrix cookbook does not help in the slightest.

For example, if I have some vectors:
$F$, $n$, $W_1$, $W_2$

Then I have the expression that evaluates to a scalar:
$s = F^T F (W_1 - W_2)^T n$

How do I take the partial of $s$ with respect to $F$?

I suppose in the above example, the second dot product can be pulled out as a constant, then we just have the gradient of $F^T F$ wrt $F$. But what are the general rules.

I'd like a rigorous explanation of the rules. It seems to *almost* work correctly if I just treat each vector as a scalar and do single variable calculus, but not quite. I'd like a fast way to do it instead of thinking about each individual element of the expression and doing scalar calculus then regrouping (that seems to take forever).

Comment: this is explained in many books. What you need to search for is "Fréchet derivative", pay attention to the chain rule and the form of the derivative of any multilinear map. Now observe that, in your expression, almost all (if not all) is linear.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the function simply writes $\phi=\alpha \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}=\alpha (x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2)$. You are required to compute the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_n}$ using standard differentiation rules.

The gradient can be stored in a N-point column vector
$2\alpha \mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function $s : (\mathbb{R}^n)^{4} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $s(F, W_1, W_2, n) = F^TF(W_1 - W_2)^Tn$. You want the Frechet derivative of $s$ with respect to $F$. The notation for this is $D_Fs : (\mathbb{R}^n)^{4} \to \mathbb{R}$. At each point $(F, W_1, W_2, n) \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^{4}$, $D_Fs(F, W_1, W_2, n)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. See the beginning of any multivariable analysis book for a treatment of the Frechet derivative for maps between Euclidean spaces. For example, see "Introduction to Analysis in Several Variables" here: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/math-521-522-basic-undergraduate-analysis-advanced-calculus/.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the dot product notation and the product rule

<sub>I am using ***bold italic*** for vectors, **bold roman** for matrix and *italics* for scalars.</sub>

Say you have $u = \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{F} $ and you want to take the partial with (all the components) of $\boldsymbol{F}$.

$$ \begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{u}' & =\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}u\\
 & =\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}\left(\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}\right)\\
 & =\left(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}\boldsymbol{F}\right)\cdot\boldsymbol{F}+\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\left(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}\boldsymbol{F}\right)\\
 & =\left(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}\boldsymbol{F}\right)\cdot 2\;\boldsymbol{F}\\
 & =\left({\bf 1}^{\top}\right)2\;\boldsymbol{F}=2\;\boldsymbol{F}
\end{aligned} $$

Note that $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}}\boldsymbol{F} = {\bf 1}$ is the identity *matrix*, and the dot product is equivalent to the transposed product $\boldsymbol{A}\cdot \boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{A}^\top \boldsymbol{B}$. The result $\boldsymbol{u}'$ is a *vector* as it represent the partial of $u$ with each component of $\boldsymbol{F}$.

The above is entirely analogous to $y=x^2$ and $y' = 2x$.

The general rules of vector calculus are as follows

- Sclar product: $\lambda\, \boldsymbol{x} \Rightarrow \{ \lambda x_i \}$
- Addition : $\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{y} \Rightarrow \{ x_i + y_i \}$
- Dot product: $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} \Rightarrow \sum_i x_i y_i $
- Outer product: $\boldsymbol{x} \odot \boldsymbol{y} \Rightarrow \{ x_i y_j \}$
- Distribution: $\boldsymbol{x} ( \boldsymbol{y} \cdot \boldsymbol{z} ) = (\boldsymbol{x} \odot \boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{z}$
- Scalar Differential: $ (\lambda \boldsymbol{x}) = \lambda \boldsymbol{x}' $ (assumes $\lambda$ is constant)
- Addition Differential: $(\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{y})' = \boldsymbol{x}' + \boldsymbol{y}'$
- Product Rule: $ ( \boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y})' = \boldsymbol{x}' \cdot \boldsymbol{y} + \boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y}'$

and other rules that can be derived from the above, similar to regular calculus, but with care not preserve the order of multiplications (as to not violate the distribution rule above).

Comment: I don't quite understand your written rules. You wrote the ' operator on the left hand side sometimes, but usually not. Was that a typo?

Comment: The `'` denotes differentiation. $\boldsymbol{x}'$ is the derivative (with respect to something).

Comment: So your suggestion is to convert all the vectors into scalars then do scalar calculus? Seems inefficient and hard to do the reshaping back to vector/matrix form at the end as the expression gets more complicated

Comment: @user3180 - that was not my suggestion. Treat vectors as vectors and use the algebra rules above to simplify and work out whatever problem there is. I was just noting above what the definition/meaning of different symbols is. Are your concerns beyond what is posted in the question?